# what might cause a print error in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a long running script that every hour opens a file, prints to it and closes the file.  I've recently found very rarely, the print is failing, not because I'm testing the status of the print itself but rather due to the fact of missing entries in the file until the system is actually rebooted!

I do trap for file open failures and write a message to syslog when that happens and I'm not seeing any open failures so I'm now guessing it may be the print that is failing.  I'm not trapping the print failures, which I suspect most people don't but am now going to update that one print.

Meanwhile, my question is does anyone know what types of situations could cause a print statement to fail when there is plenty of disk storage and no contention for a file which has been successfully opened in append mode?

Answer (score 7):

You could be out of memory (ENOMEM) or over a filesize limit (E2BIG or SIGXFSZ). You could have an old-fashioned I/O error (EIO). You could have a race condition if the script is run concurrently or if the file is accessed over NFS. And, of course, you could have an error in the expression whose value you would print.

An exotic cause that I once saw is that a CPU heatsink failure can lead to sprintf spuriously failing, causing some surprising results including writing garbage to file descriptors.

Finally, I remind you that print will often write its stuff in an I/O buffer. This means two things. (1) You need to check the result of close() as well. (2) If you print but you don't immediately close() or flush() then your data can be buffered and not actually written until much later (or not at all if the process dies horribly).

Comment: good guess but I just looked and had 67GB of free memory at the time.  I also saw the same script that was trying to update this file simultaneously writes a compressed file via Compress::Zlib every second and it stalled for 30 seconds before the print failed and immediately restarted right about the time the print occurred.   So it seems the filesystem was temporarily 'unavailable'?

Comment: If your filesystem was temporarily 'unavailable' that means that you likely have a hard disk error, check your system log.